# Sufficient conditions for stabilizability of [A,B]

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, matrix-rank, control-theory, discrete-time

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be $n\times n$ and $m\times n$ matrices, respectively, the pair $(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})$ is stabilizable if there exists an $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{K}$ such that $\rho(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K}')<1$, with $\rho(\cdot)$ denoting the spectral radius.

Stabilizability of $(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})$ can also be reached if for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $\mathbf{A}$ such that $|\lambda|\geq1$ holds that $\text{rank}[\lambda \mathbb{I} - \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}]=n$, with $\mathbb{I}$ the identity matrix.

**Question:**
Can sufficient conditions on $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be found such that the pair $(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})$ is stabilizable? For example, what if $m=n$ and $\rho(\mathbf{A})<1$?

I tried to find an upper bound for $\rho(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K}')$ and work with the ranks, but did't go anywhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: The rank condition here is for controllability. Stabilizability requires the non stable eigenvalues to be controllable. You should clarify whether you are talking about controllability or stabilizability.

Comment: I am interested in stabilizability, thus I edit my question to make it more precise. However, controllability should entail stabilizability so hints on sufficient conditions on A,B for controllability would be also welcomed.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is a bit clearer now but I am not sure to understand what you mean by upper bound in the last statement. An upper bound on the spectral radius for some $K$ fixed or you want an upper-bound for which there is a $K$ such that this upper-bound is true? Regarding the case $\rho(A)$, then the system is obviously stabilizable.

Comment: Given that I want $\rho(A+BK')<1$, I tried to derive an upper bound for $\rho(A+BK')$ to see what conditions on the matrices could have pushed the upper bound to be lower than 1, but I struggled finding the bound. You suggest that for the case $\rho(A)<1$ the system is obviously stabilizable, but I fail to see it. If $\rho(A)<1$ then there is a $K$ such that $\rho(A+BK')<1$?

Comment: Yes, $K=0$ satisfies that.

Comment: Ok, I agree. However, exception made for this trivial case, I find it hard to find another $K$ such that $\rho(A+BK')<1$.

Comment: Any small enough gain will satisfy too using a continuity argument.

Comment: For instance, let $K=-\epsilon B$, then we we get that $A+BK'=A-\epsilon BB'$. Can you show that for small enough $\epsilon>0$, this matrix is Schur stable?

Comment: I see where you'are going, but cannot provide a formal proof of Shur stability of $A-\epsilon BB'$.

Comment: This follows from the continuity of eigenvalues of a matrix with respect to its entries.

Comment: Ok, so you mean using Bauer-Fike theorem to show that $\rho(A-\epsilon BB')$ is arbitrarily close to $\rho(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what the person who wrote the answer wants, so I will start with something and update my answer according to the following discussion, if there is any.

So, there is a necessary and sufficient condition for stabilizability that can be stated in terms of a Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI). Stabilizability of the pair $(A,B)$ is equivalent to the existence of a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ (abbrv. $P\succ0$) such that

$$N_B(APA^T-P)N_B^T\prec0,$$ where $N_B$ is a basis of the left nullspace of $B$; i.e. $N_BB=0$ and $N_B$ of maximum rank.

This a condition in terms of $A$ and $B$, but it is implicit. When this condition holds, then there exists a $K$ such that $\rho(A+BK)<1$.

It can be generalized to $$N_B(APA^T-\alpha^{2}P)N_B^T\prec0$$ with $\alpha>0$. In this case there will exist a $K$ such that $\rho(A+BK)<\alpha$.

I am not sure how well this answers the question and I am happy to discuss about it.

Comment: I gave some more thoughts to this answer and I decided to accepted as I think it gives an interesting insight on how conditions on $A$ and $B$ can make or not the system stabilizable. One doubt though, if $B$ is $n\times n$ and invertible, the basis of the left nullspace of $B$ will be empty. Does this means it is enough to have $APA'-P$ negative definite for stabilizability?

Comment: The case I am describing is when the rank of $B$ is less than $n$. If the rank of $B$ is $n$, then there is no condition to stabilizability. This can be found in the book by Skelton, Iwasaki, and Grigoriadis.